# Laravel insert default value instead of data sent via request

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm facing a peculiar issue on my Laravel app that when I insert data to the database, it always inserts the default value instead of the data sent via a post request. So I dd() the value before inserting them into the database and the correct data showing. But on the database, it always inserts the default value in the migration file.

The same code works fine for another modal.

**HTML form**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label for="is_free">Is Free</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="is_free" required>
            <option value="1">Free</option>
            <option value="0">Pro Only</option>
        </select>
        @error('is_free')
        <div class="text-danger mt-2 small ">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->mediumText('content');
        $table->tinyInteger('is_free')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
Chapter::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'slug' => $request->slug,
    'description' => $request->description,
    'content' => $request->content,
    'is_free' => $request->is_free,
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Chapter Model, make sure you have `$fillable` property with correct properties:

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['title','slug','description','content','is_free'];
....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the issue. I am so stupid.

Comment: it happens, please mark the answer as accepted so we consider this question as "answered"